# Bootstrap Responsive Product Grid

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a product grid built upon AngularJS data - where there will be **images and product details (text)**

The **text** sometimes extends to the 2nd line, causing havoc.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div data-ng-repeat="s in Results">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <div>
                    <img ng-src="{{s.ProductImage}}" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div>
                    {{s.Store}} {{s.Category}} {{s.ProductName}}
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

How do I fix it so that `<div>`s all have the same height? 
I tried to look online for solutions, but I think I am 50% there. Please help.

**Note: I Don't want to hide content.**

Comment: I think the only option is to create three containing columns `(col-xs-4)` an do a repeat inside each and split out every item into the proper column based upon the count. I don't know how to do that in angular, so I just upvoted the question. I've had this problem multiple times in my language of choice.

Comment: My solution doesn't make the heights equal, you'd need `jquery` for that. You'd loop through all of the items after they've been loaded and set the minimum-height to the same as the largest product `div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing for anyone who stumbles on this again in the future.

## Javascript

```
function ResizeToLargestElement(element) {
    var maxHeight = -1;
    if ($(element).length > 0) {
        $(element).each(function () {
            maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
        });

        $(element).each(function () {
            $(this).height(maxHeight);
        });
    }
}
```

## Without AngularJS

For those who aren't using AngularJS, just call `ResizeToLargestElement()` when data changes or the window is resized using

```
$(window).resize(function() {
       ResizeToLargestElement('.AutoResizeToLargestElement');
});`
```

## With AngularJS

The idea is to call the `ResizeToLargestElement()` function whenever `$scope.Results` changes or when the window resizes.

To know when `$scope.Results` changed is easy, but to know when elements (that are bound to it) finished rendering is not easy. To do that, you need a AngularJS directive.

To know when the window re-sizes, use `angular.element($window).on('resize', function () {...});`

## HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div data-ng-repeat="s in Results" data-ng-repeat-finished> <!--ADDED Directive-->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail AutoResizeToLargestElement"> <!--ADDED Class-->
                <div>
                    <img ng-src="{{s.ProductImage}}" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div>
                    {{s.Store}} {{s.Category}} {{s.ProductName}}
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!--REMOVED clearfix-->
    </div>
</div>
```

## MyDirectives.js

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('ngRepeatFinished', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

## mycontroller.js

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function (ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
    ResizeToLargestElement(".AutoResizeToLargestElement");
});

angular.element($window).on('resize', function () {   
    ResizeToLargestElement(".AutoResizeToLargestElement");
});
```

Note: this requires you to include `$window` in the AngularJS dependency list.
I.E. `angular.module('myApp').controller('....', ['...., '$window', ....]);`

Comment: An excellent and thorough solution to my exact problem. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the height of each product dynamic, you will need to split the results into columns. And then use `ng-if` to put the right items in the right column. Every 3rd item will go into the same column. To set them to different columns, just reduce the `$index` by `1` for each extra column.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div ng-repeat="s in Results"> <a href="#" class="thumbnail" ng-if="$index%3==0">
            <div>
              <img ng-src="{{s.ProductImage}}" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div>{{s.Store}} {{s.Category}} {{s.ProductName}}</div>
          </a>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div ng-repeat="s in Results"> <a href="#" class="thumbnail" ng-if="($index-1)%3==0">
            <div>
              <img ng-src="{{s.ProductImage}}" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div>{{s.Store}} {{s.Category}} {{s.ProductName}}</div>
          </a>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div ng-repeat="s in Results"> <a href="#" class="thumbnail" ng-if="($index-2)%3==0">
            <div>
              <img ng-src="{{s.ProductImage}}" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div>{{s.Store}} {{s.Category}} {{s.ProductName}}</div>
          </a>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually restrict the height of the `div` and use an `overflow`. Use something like

```
<div class="col-xs-4" style="height:200px; overflow: auto;">Content</div>
```

Or, you could always use a responsive table (`<table class="table table-responsive">`) for your layout.

Comment: Don't want to hide content. Sorry updating question.

Comment: Then, just get the height of the `div` with the maximum height and set all heights to it. Or use a table layout.

Comment: Getting maximum height - did this but... can you call a function on browser resize?

Comment: The height of a `div` won't change on browser resize, right?

Comment: it might. I think it's `$( window ).resize(function() {...}` let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this problem is to add clearfix class to hidden divs for earch size of viewport. for example:

Large size: i want 6 columns (large desktops)
Medium size: i want 4 columns (Desktops)
Tablets: i want 3 coumns
phones: i want 2 columns

so i have the products list:

```
<?php $count=1; foreach($productList as $product) : ?>
    <div class="item col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            Picture and description
    </div><!-- /item -->

    <?php if( ($count%2)==0) {?><div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div><?php }?>
    <?php if( ($count%3)==0) {?><div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div><?php }?>
    <?php if( ($count%4)==0) {?><div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div><?php }?>
    <?php if( ($count%6)==0) {?><div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div><?php }?>

<?php $count++; endforeach?>
```